# Add click event from mouseover callback

Tags: javascript, events, click, mouseover

In the below example, when the user hovers over the svg#test2 a second rect should appear (#rect2). When the user clicks on #rect2 a click event should fire. The first approach works as expected, but in the second example clicking on #rect2 fires the mouseover event and not the click event. Can someone explain why this is the case?

Please note that the second example DOES work if mouseover is changed to mouseenter, OR if stopProgation is called in the mouseover event. I don't really understand why these approaches fix the problem.

SVG:

```html
<svg width="40em" height="20em">
   <svg id="test2" width="10" height="150" x="30", y="30">
      <rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="blue"></rect>
   </svg>
</svg>
```

Approach 1 (works)

```js
d3.select('#test2')
   .append('rect')
   .attr('id','rect1')
   .attr('visibility','hidden')
   .attr('height','50%')
   .attr('width','50%')
   .on('click', function(){
      alert('click');
   });

d3.select('#test2')
   .on('mouseover', function(){
      console.log('mouseover');

      d3.select('#rect1').attr('visibility','visible');
   });
```

Approach 2 (click event not fired):

```js
d3.select('#test2')
   .on('mouseover', function(){
      console.log('mouseover');

      d3.select(this)
         .append('rect')
         .attr('height','50%').attr('width','50%')
         .on('click', function(){
            alert('click');
         });
   });
```

Any thoughts as to why the latter doesn't work, or why it does work with mouseenter / stopPropagation?

Comment: Why would you add an event listener everytime a mouseover event is fired?

Comment: As far as i can see you probably wouldn't. That said, as far as i can see the second example should still 'work', even if it's weird. I'm just trying to understand why it behaves the way it does.